# Android: nothing on the screen with the List View tutorial

Tags: android

I'm following [the List View tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

and I have this code (very minor modifications):

```
public class GroupsActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.groups_layout, R.array.repetitions_array));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

R.layout.groups_layout is an .xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

the problem is that I see nothing on screen.
Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the Logcat output?  Are you sure that your array contains items?  Maybe try setting your listview item layout_height to "wrap_content" instead of "fill_parent"

Comment: where do you define the `repetitions_array`? and did you actually fill it with data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't provide the id of an array resource in the ArrayAdapter constructor. You need the actual array object. Try this instead:

```
String your_array_contents[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.repetitions_array);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.groups_layout, your_array_contents));
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that R.array.repetitions_array is empty